# How do I generate a ranking/sort cells automatically in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

For example I have a table with a caption and some numerical data, such as:

```
Mary | Sue | Mike
-----------------
 100 | 20  | 30 
-----------------
```

I want to generate a ranking, i.e.

```
1. Mary
2. Mike
3. Sue
```

Is there a way to do it automatically? Automatically as in not using "Data > Sort" manually each time the numbers at hand are recalculated.

I know about the RANK function, that's the inverse of what I want (RANK gives you the data's rank, I want the rank's data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Example](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6LXy9sguZVkSXVqdnBWd0tVWUk/edit?usp=sharing)Yes, there is a way to do it automatically, It uses RANK, twice (once to sort and a second time to deal with duplicate values)

The example shows 2 ways of doing it without macros;

sheet1 uses RANK, COUNTIF and VLOOKUP (recommended)
sheet2 uses HLOOKUP, VLOOKUP, COUNTIF, MAX and MIN

Comment: This appears incomplete; please properly link your example.

Comment: I've added the example. It shows 2 ways of auto-sorting text

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data is in the upper left corner of your spreadsheet, do the following in column B5 after setting columns `{A5, A6, A7} = {1, 2, 3}`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1, MATCH(LARGE($A$2:$C$2, A5),  $A$2:$C$2,  0))
```

Then drag the formula down to get the remaining ranked data.